# Construir/iniciar objeto via parâmetro string em uma função

Tags: javascript, funções

Preciso iniciar objetos dinamicamente com JavaScript

Ex:

#### Classe de exemplo:

```
function sayhello() {
    this.init = function() {
        alert('Hello');
    }
}
```

#### Função para carregar e instanciar classes dinamicamente:

```
function iniciaClasse(nomeDaClasse) {
    return new nomeDaClasse();
}
```

#### Código final (de execução):

```
var variavelqualquer = iniciaClasse('sayhello');
```

#### O problema:

Isso está me retornando um erro, e eu entendo mais ou menos o porquê, uma vez que passo uma *string* no parâmetro `nomeDaClasse`, já que não tenho o construtor da classe a ser instanciada de imediato.

A função `iniciaClasse()` é um module *loader*, e vai carregar, iniciar e retornar a classe que eu informar, portanto, quando eu chamo tal função, o construtor (`sayhello`) ainda não existe.

Sendo assim...

**Se eu fizer:** `iniciaClasse(sayHello)` - Obtenho um erro porque `sayHello()` não existe ainda

**Se eu fizer:** `iniciaClasse('sayHello')` - Obtenho um erro porque o parâmetro passado é uma *string* (creio eu que é por isso)

Existe alguma forma para sanar isso?

Comment: tenta usar o padrão de projeto singleton.

Comment: Alguma resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade do jeito que está o código e usar `iniciaClasse(sayHello)` não dá erro algum, se deu está fazendo outra coisa.

Para fazer o que deseja precisa pegar o identificador da função no dicionário da janela para poder chamá-la, assim:

```js
function sayhello() {
    this.init = function() {
        console.log('Hello');
    }
}

function iniciaClasse(nomeDaClasse) {
    var funcao = window[nomeDaClasse];
    return new funcao();
}

var variavelqualquer = iniciaClasse('sayhello');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/CallFunctionReturned.js)

Isso resolve o que está na pergunta não mas faz o código ser útil. Aí é outro problema.

Comment: Está dando o seguinte erro: (index):76 Uncaught TypeError: funcao is not a constructor
    at iniciaClasse ((index):76)
    at window.onload ((index):79) veja no JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oqvsxk9L/

Comment: @AllanAndrade não sei porque começou acontecer isso, na época funcionava, esse é uma dos problemas do JS, ele quebra compatibilidade.

Answer (score 0):

da forma como está feito, você teria de pegar a função que instancia o objeto direto no window, isto pode ser problemático, especialmente se esta função for redeclarada em outra parte do script.

Neste caso, te aconselho a utilizar a tentar modularizar o seu `script`. Uma boa seria utilizar o `RequireJS`, mesmo que não o faça de forma assíncrona. Caso seja algo bem simples que queira construir, pode usar o seguinte script.

```js
(function () {
  var libs = [];
  
  Object.defineProperty(window, "define", {
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function (name, callback) {
      libs[name] = callback();
    }
  });
  
  Object.defineProperty(window, "require", {
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function (name) {
      return libs[name];
    }
  });
})();

define("world", function () {
  var World = function () {};  
  World.prototype.sayHello = function () {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }  
  return World;
});

var MyClass = require("world");
var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.sayHello();
```

fazendo desta forma, você pode até colocar os `define` em arquivos `js` separados e depois fazer um `bundle` e `minify` destes arquivos, e o seu script irá continuar à funcionar da maneira esperada.